# regex which could exclude a substring by using negative lookaround

Tags: javascript, regex

my input is:  
`<span question_number="18"> blah blah blah 1</span><span question_number="19"> blah blah blah 2</span>`

and I want my regex to match this 
`<span question_number="somenumber">xxxx</span>` pattern 
and the desired output is 1.somenumber 2.xxxx

I wrote a naive solution which could cover 
`<span question_number="18"> blah blah blah 1</span>` 
`<span question_number="19"> blah blah blah 2</span>`
notice: they are on different lines 
the output is : `18`, `blah blah blah 1` and `19`,`blah blah blah 2`

but when the input is `<span question_number="18"> blah blah blah 1</span><span question_number="19"> blah blah blah 2</span>`
which is on the same line

my output is `18`,  `blah blah blah 1</span><span question_number="19"> blah blah blah 2`

how could I bypass this problem?

Update: 
regex: `\<span question_number=(?:\")*(\d*)(?:\")*>(.*)<\/span>`

testinput: 
case1 -> two lines of code 
`<span question_number="54">often graces doorways tied into ropes called</span>` 
`<span question_number="54">often graces doorways tied into ropes called <i>ristras</i>.</span>`
           case2 -> one line of code 
`<span question_number="54">often graces doorways tied into ropes called</span><span question_number="54">often graces doorways tied into ropes called <i>ristras</i>.</span>`

Comment: Ungreedy your quantifier. `*?` instead of just `*`. Or, better still, don't use Regex to parse HTML!

Comment: Can you show us your solution so far?

Comment: @ExplosionPills could you have a look please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already working with JavaScript / HTML, rather than use a regular expression to extract data from the html it's generally much easier to use DOM querying tools that are already available in the browser.

```
const d = document.createElement("div");
d.innerHTML = yourSpanContent;

Array.from(d.querySelectorAll("span")).map(span =>
  `1. ${span.getAttribute("question_number")} 2. ${span.innerText}`
);
```

If the HTML you are working with is already in a DOM then you can select from that DOM and essentially remove the first two lines.

Comment: @MohanL you need to include more information in your question such as how this HTML is being generated and how you are extracting the data.  I'm not sure what you mean "before I generate the DOM"

Answer (score 0):

This will match anything in a span tag regardless of where it is in a line.

```
 /(<span[^>]*>)[^<]*(<\/span>)/g
```

Can you post your code?